# Flutter App Crashing on iOS Device on Version 1.12.123 hot fix 8

Tags: macos, flutter, dart

I am having issues running my Flutter apps on my iPhone 11 device. The app runs fine on the simulator. It is when I install it on my device with `flutter run` that the problem occurs. I ran `flutter doctor` and it said there were no issues found.

What is happening is that the app installs on the device seemingly fine. However, when you launch it (and trust the developer in iOS settings), the app just crashes.

I tried testing this with a fresh Flutter app, to see if it was a problem with the recent update to 1.12.13 hotfix 8. And, even the fresh app is crashing on my phone.

Is there a solution for this problem or am I going to have to downgrade to an older version of Flutter?

Thanks

Comment: Hey man, did you able to solve the issue. I think I have a similar to your issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/52962 and I see no support from the Flutter team.